# HTML displaying Error

Tags: html, youtube, gmail, wso2-esb

Hi I am trying to send an html in an Email.(Support related stuff)

Problem is that it is working fine on my local notepad. 
**LINKEDIN** image is right on its place.

[image]

But when I send this html in gmail mail to user by my backend system (storing html in wso2 local entry point) then this **LINKEDIN** Icon move a little up.

[image]

**Also Link of youtube video is also showing as attachment.**

How can I solve this?

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center;padding:0px 0px">
            <table align="center" bgcolor="#505050" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:650px;margin:auto;text-align:center" width="100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="text-align:center">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/mysitelink" target="_blank"><img height="10%" width="5%" border="0" src="http://twitter-256.png" style="display:inline-block;padding:0px 8px"/></a>
                    <a href="https://facebook.com/mysitelink" target="_blank"><img height="6%" width="5% border=" src="http://facebooklogo.png" style="display:inline-block;padding:0px 8px"/></a>
                    <a href="https://youtube.com/mysitelink" ><img height="10%" width="5%" border="0" src="http://youtube.png" style="padding-top:100px:display:inline-block;padding:0px 8px"/></a>
                    <a href="https://linkedin.com/mysitelink" target="_blank"><img height="20%" width="7%" border="0" src="http://Linkedin.png" style="position: relative;top: 12px;display:inline-block;padding:0px 6px"/></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="text-align:center">
                    <p style="letter-spacing:3px;font-size:12px;margin:0;line-height:18px;text-align:center;font-family:'Nunito Sans',Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#bababa;padding:20px 30px">
                    <span><a href="http://contact/" style="text-decoration:none;letter-spacing:3px;font-size:12px;margin:0;line-height:18px;font-family:'Nunito Sans',Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#bababa;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;padding-bottom:3%" target="_blank">CONTACT US</a></span>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing Semicolon in your styling and also you had a top: 12px; that was causing your linked in to be out of positioning just copy and paste my code I altered for you.

I Hope I was able to help!

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;padding:0px 0px">
        <table align="center" bgcolor="#505050" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:650px;margin:auto;text-align:center" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="text-align:center">
              
                <a href="https://twitter.com/mysitelink" target="_blank">
                <img height="auto" width="5%" border="0" src="http://twitter-256.png" style="display:inline-block;padding:0px 8px;"/></a>
                
                <a href="https://facebook.com/mysitelink" target="_blank">
                <img height="auto" width="5%" border="0" src="http://facebooklogo.png" style="display:inline-block; padding:0px 8px;"/></a>
                
                <a href="https://youtube.com/mysitelink"  target="_blank" >
                <img height="auto" width="5%" border="0" src="http://youtube.png" style="display:inline-block; padding:0px 8px;"/></a>

                <a href="https://linkedin.com/mysitelink" target="_blank">
                <img height="auto" width="5%" border="0" src="http://Linkedin.png" style="display:inline-block;padding:0px 8px;"/></a>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="text-align:center">
                <p style="letter-spacing:3px;font-size:12px;margin:0;line-height:18px;text-align:center;font-family:'Nunito Sans',Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#bababa;padding:20px 30px">
                <span><a href="http://contact/" style="text-decoration:none;letter-spacing:3px;font-size:12px;margin:0;line-height:18px;font-family:'Nunito Sans',Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#bababa;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;padding-bottom:3%;" target="_blank">CONTACT US</a></span>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Hey can you please tell where exactly I am doing these two mistakes? 
because I cannot copy paste it exactly. I have changed link and many things before posting question

Comment: in your code where you linkedin <img height="20%" width="7%" border="0" src="http://Linkedin.png" style="position: relative;top: 12px; <--REMOVE top:12px;//

Comment: also check all your styles because you will see some styles that have missing semicolons in the end of all your of your style padding  (twitter,Facebook,YouTube,LinkedIn)style padding must have  ";" like so --> (padding:0px 8px;) @MikiJay

Comment: and as a side note in  my opinion i'd keep my height to auto and just change the width to however you'd like on the img style.

Comment: Ok thank you I will  try it in morning and let you know :)

Comment: Do you have any Idea y youtube video link is showing in attachemt?

Comment: i'm glad i was able to help, i'm not sure about the attachment situation but ill look into it and let you know.

Comment: I edited my snippet again because I found some more errors in your code if possible copy and paste my code, you shouldn't get the YouTube attachment but if you do, That problem is mostly coming from just your email provider that your using to send your html, because you are using images gmail might thinks there attachments.

Comment: please vote and accept my Answer if I was able to help, and Let me know if you have further Questions. @MikiJay

Comment: sure @twinaholic :)